# Kafka on Docker cannot connect from other container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

Hi I’m using Spotify/Kafka and am running it with

`docker run —name ka -p 9092:9092 -p 2181:2181 —env ADVERTISED_HOST=localhost —env ADVERTISED_PORT 2181 —net mynet spotify/kafka`

I make sure I run my second container using the same net and I can ping the Kafka container using ka.mynet

Also in this second container I downloaded kafka and it’s shell scripts and I’m able to do a

`./kafka-topics.sh —zookeeper ka.mynet —list`  and see the “Test” topic

Now any attempt to produce or consume spits out errors. Producer complains about something to do with not finding a leader.

Other Googling has led me to believe it has something to do with the advertised host.

Comment: FWIW, for actual up-to-date Kafka versions, see https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html

Comment: Did you wait before your kafka came up? Can you share the dockerfile or compose file?

Comment: Hey @cricket_007 I want to use apache kafka and the doco you linked talks about docker-machine on Windows which I believe is no longer necessary, there is a "docker for windows" option now but thank you for your reply.

Comment: @ShankarShastri I'm using this dockerfile here: https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka

Comment: Again, Spotify Kafka doesn't run the latest Kafka. That's my main point. And no, Docker machine still exists, and is recommended outside of Linux machines because the `net=host` option doesn't work elsewhere. However, that doesn't stop you from *trying* to run those containers from https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1):

Ok it seems like the only way to get this to work is to assign my machine's current IP address as the ADVERTISED_HOST env variable.

So if my machine's IP is 192.168.1.11 then:

```
docker run —name ka -p 9092:9092 -p 2181:2181 —env ADVERTISED_HOST=192.168.1.11 —env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 —net mynet spotify/kafka
```

Comment: you don't need to hardcode ADVERTISED_HOST, you can try this as well:
` ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active\`` `

Comment: docker run -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=`docker-machine ip \`docker-machine active\`` --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka

Comment: @Shankar OP said in comments they're not using Docker machine